# MotionLayout: multiple cumulative transitions

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I'm using `MotionLayout` and am trying to apply a series of transitions (defined in `MotionScene` file).  For example Transition1 changes position of View1, and then Transition2 subsequently changes position of View2.  The issue I'm seeing is that Transition2 is causing View1 to revert to it's original layout.  I'm triggering the transitions using calls to `transitionToState()` (I've also tried explicitly providing start/end state for transition using `setTransition()` and then calling `transitionToEnd()`).

I saw comment in https://www.raywenderlich.com/8883-motionlayout-tutorial-for-android-getting-started that

> if you don’t provide an end constraint for a view, it will
>   disappear. This happens because the library doesn’t know which
>   constraints it should apply at the end of the animation

Is it necessary to also include info on View1 layout in `ConstraintSet` for Transition2?

There is a "Multi State" example in https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ConstraintLayoutExamples/blob/master/README.md but it looks like transitions included all start from single base state (rather than being "cumulative")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@hoford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2558442/hoford) said, the ConstraintSets are not merged each time they change. Apparently, this is also not possible without using reflection, although it would definitely be useful. Anyway, here is how to do it using reflection (through a few extension functions).

I did create my [own `TransitionListener`](https://gist.github.com/jossiwolf/37753bb1af051860d7f8d836e17fd29e) base class to provide support annotations and readable value names.
The extension functions can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/jossiwolf/b018bd39b5e88bbb55ef02552a5cb67e).

What you can do is merge the two `ConstraintSets` and then mutate the `endConstraintSet` which can be obtained through `TransitionListener#onTransitionChange`:

```
class AccumulativeTransitionListener: TransitionListener() {

        var didApplyConstraintSet = false

        override fun onTransitionChange(view: MotionLayout, @IdRes startConstraintSetId: Int, @IdRes endConstraintSetId: Int, progress: Float) {
            if (!didApplyConstraintSet) {
                // Let's retrieve our ConstraintSets first
                val startConstraintSet = view.getConstraintSet(startConstraintSetId)
                val endConstraintSet = view.getConstraintSet(endConstraintSetId)
                // Merge them (using an extension function)
                val mergedConstraintSet = startConstraintSet + endConstraintSet
                // Clear + Set them
                endConstraintSet.setConstraints(mergedConstraintSet)
                didApplyConstraintSet = true
            }
        }

        override fun onTransitionCompleted(view: MotionLayout, @IdRes constraintSetId: Int) {
            didApplyConstraintSet = false
        }

    }
```

To not merge and apply the `ConstraintSets` each time `TransitionListener#onTransitionChange` is being called, there's a simple helper variable.

Lastly, you have to attach the listener to your `MotionLayout`:

```
val accumulativeListener = AccumulativeTransitionListener()
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(accumulativeListener)
```

Let me know if that works or if there are any bugs!

Comment: I am assuming these extension functions are only available in Kotlin. Is there a way to adapt them to Java. I need to merge the start and end ConstraintSets to avoid views jumping back to their original positions!

Answer (score 2):

Transitions are not delta of state. They go from state to state.
ConstraintSets define those states.

ConstraintSets (within the context of a MotionScene) define a state which is the base layout + your changes described in the  tag.

Comment: OK, so in my case I'll also need to define current layout of View1 (after Transition1) in ConstraintSet for Transitions2 (and also a different ConstraintSet if Transitions1 didn't occur)?  My challenge is that we have several transitions changing multiple different views....and there's no guarantee a particular transition has happened before....so permutations grow pretty large (if all combinations of modified View layouts need to be defined for each transition)

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly I am looking for the answer to this. I see the answer using extension functions. I will try it. And, I am realizing that everything is based on the inflated state of the layout! The same exact thing is happening to me that the views flip back to their original positions before the new transition plays out! Why didnt Android think of a better idea. Its either the extension functions or the permutations hard coded into lengthy motion scene files.

Comment: This is a design choice MotionLayout take. You either have the  states be the main concept or the Transitions be the main concept.  MotionLayout is based on ConstraintLayout.  With Android ObjectAnimators Transitions are the main concept but that adds its own complexity. 

MotionLayout does have the ability to mutate all states using ViewTransition.
You can also update ConstraintSets in the MotionLayout.